# padding for DIV on safari is skipped on the left side

Tags: html, css, safari, padding

I have just encountered very weird behavior as ONLY on Safar.. as padding for div inside body is not respected on the left side.

HTML code looks like:

```
<html>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <div style="padding:12px;">asd</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and SAFARI output looks like:

[image]

Does anyone knows why I am getting such result? or maybe this is correct and I don't know something? (but as I previously said it works properly ie. on Chrome)

Answer (score 0):

for others: just reinstall Safari... now it is displaying div correctly..

[image]